# This query assigns a value to all records in the table, but I want to assign the value only to the last record

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables. One is `publisher_info` and the other one is `unique_code`. I want to assign the `u_code` column value from the `unique_code` table to the `publisher_info.u_code` column. Instead of assigning the value to last record, the query assigns and updated the value of all records. How can I fix this?

```
$record = "UPDATE publisher_info 
           SET u_code = (SELECT u_code 
                         FROM unique_code 
                         where unique_code.id = ".mysqli_insert_id($conn).")";
```

Comment: I have two tables one is publisher_info and other one is unique_code. I want to assign u_code coloumn value from unique_code table to publisher_info u_code coloumn . Instead Of assigning the value to last record the query assigns and updated the value of all record.Plz help me with this

Comment: You have a `WHERE` clause in your inner query, but there isn't one in the actual `UPDATE` query. You'll need to add an appropriate `WHERE ...` there to prevent it from updating every record.

Comment: how can I add that where clause??

Comment: At the time you're executing this, have you just inserted a record into `publisher_info`, or `unique_code`?

Comment: I am little confuse, Why it is the last record does you have any other info so we can think what to use after WHERE...

Comment: `$record = "UPDATE publisher_info 
           SET u_code = (SELECT u_code 
                         FROM unique_code 
                         where unique_code.id = ".mysqli_insert_id($conn).") where something ";`
Here you need to add the field which make your row unique in the `publisher_info` table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$record = "UPDATE publisher_info SET u_code = (SELECT u_code FROM unique_code ORDER BY unique_code.id DESC LIMIT 1)";

Comment: can you explain you solution?

Comment: I can't use desc limit 1 cz if more than one user register simultanoulsly so conflict is occuring. So I used mysqli_insert_id...Is there any other way by which I cn write that query using mysqli_insert_id???

Comment: $record = "UPDATE publisher_info SET u_code = (SELECT u_code FROM unique_code ORDER BY unique_code.id DESC LIMIT 1)";         this query is also assigning same value to all the records..

Comment: how can I fetch last record from databse and update  it by assigning value from other table ???

Comment: $record = "UPDATE publisher_info SET u_code = (SELECT u_code FROM unique_code where unique_code.id = ".mysqli_insert_id($conn).") where something ";  this query i working but it assigns the value to second last record and I want last record...I wrote this query                                                                             $record = "UPDATE publisher_info SET u_code = (SELECT u_code FROM unique_code where unique_code.id = publisher_info.id) where unique_code.id = ".mysqli_insert_id($conn)." ";

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer and the query finally worked was
 $record = "UPDATE publisher_info SET u_code = (SELECT u_code FROM unique_code where unique_code.id = publisher_info.id) where publisher_info.id = ".mysqli_insert_id($conn)." ";